# Diff by word instead of line in Sublime Text

Tags: git, sublimetext3, diff, git-diff

I've been using Sublime Text and Git for writing. I have made use of Sublime's `diff file` feature to compare changes between files, which gives a line-by-line difference. I would like to be able to do diff by word natively within Sublime, rather than with the terminal (i.e., using `git diff --word-diff`). I've tried the FileDiffs package but its external diff commands do not work. Is there a way to configure the default diff application in Sublime or is there a package capable of doing this?

Comment: Whilst I do see value in this, this question is off topic due to the nature of asking for an external library or resource (like a plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and:

- install [kemayo/sublime-text-git](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git)
- apply [PR 468](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/pull/468) which adds support for word-diff

Beside that, I don't know of a SublimeText3 plugin which supports it out of the box.

Comment: thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for. works great once I apply the pull request

Comment: Well done! I would hope for this PR to be one day merged into that sublime-text-git plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you SmartGit. It is very useful for me